# Changing the integral and sum in Lebesgue integral theory.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, lebesgue-integral

**Changing the integral and sum in Lebesgue integral theory.**

I considered the proof of the proposition below. Is my proof correct ?

**Proposition**

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle  \int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big|f_n (x)\big| dx < \infty
\Longrightarrow
\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \displaystyle\int f_n (x) dx =\displaystyle\int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n (x) dx 
\end{equation}

**Proof**

Let $g_N(x):=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^N f_n(x)$.

Then, I have
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\lim_{N\to \infty} g_N(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(x)
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}\big|g_N(x)\big| =\displaystyle\left|\sum_{n=0}^N f_n(x)\right|\leqq \sum_{n=0}^N \big|f_n(x)\big|\leqq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big|f_n(x)\big|.\end{equation}

From the supposition, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\big|f_n(x)\big|$ is integrable.

Thus from the Dominated Convergence Theorem, I get

\begin{equation}
\lim_{N\to \infty} \int g_N(x) dx = \int  \lim_{N\to \infty}g_N(x) dx. \cdots (\ast)
\end{equation}

The RHS of $(\ast)$ is $\displaystyle\int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(x)dx.$

The LHS of $(\ast)$ is $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to \infty} \int \sum_{n=0}^N f_n(x) dx=\lim_{N\to \infty}  \sum_{n=0}^N \int  f_n(x) dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int f_n(x) dx$.

Therefore, I get
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int f_n(x) dx=\int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(x) dx.
\end{equation}

If my proof has some problem, I would like you to point it out.

Comment: One minor point: How do you justify the statement that the limit $\lim_{N\to\infty} g_N(x)$ exists (at least a.e.)?

Comment: @JohnDawkins Well…how can I prove it ? I don't come up with the proof. Or, doesn't $\lim_{N\to \infty} g_N(x)$ necessarily exist ?

Comment: You have observed that $\sum_n|f_n(x)|<\infty$ for a.e. $x$. This implies that the series $\sum_nf_n(x)$ is (absolutely) convergent for a.e. $x$, so its partial sums...